# Llamar a una función dentro de una función (Angular 4)

Tags: angular

Tengo una duda.

Tengo una función que está permanentemente escuchando algo y quiero que cuando ese socket reciba X valor, se llame a una función.

Les paso el código:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
  if (socket !== undefined) {
    console.log('Conectado a un socket');
    socket.on('output', function(informacion){
      if (informacion.nroSerie === NROSERIE.NRO_SERIE) {
        changeValue(informacion); <-- ESTA LINEA MUESTRA EL ERROR
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Y fuera de ngOnInit tengo

```
  changeValue(informacion) {
    if (informacion !== null) {
      this.lista[0].nroSerie= informacion.nroSerie;
    }
  }
```

El error que aparece  es que no se encuentra el nombre changeValue, probé con this.changeValue y no pasa nada. ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Gracias!

Comment: changeValue esta en tu component?

Comment: Para acceder al contexto (this) es necesario ocupar funciones de 'flecha' algo como (valor)=>{}

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el callback del socket no tiene el mismo contexto que tu componente.

Puedes probar utilizando la sintaxis de las funciones de flecha (que automaticamente pasa el contexto como algumento) o pasandole tu mismo el contexto al callback.

```
ngOnInit() { 
    const socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080'); 
    if (socket !== undefined) { 
        console.log('Conectado a un socket'); 
        socket.on('output', (informacion) => { 
            if (informacion.nroSerie === NROSERIE.NRO_SERIE) { 
                changeValue(informacion); <-- ESTA LINEA MUESTRA EL ERROR 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```